# How can I convert my watercolour images to vectors for Shutterstock?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, stock-images

So, forgetting that they rejected my last image as they weren't taking content like that anymore... Shutterstock said that I wasn't allowed to use live trace in Illustrator to vectorize my watercolours.

How is everyone else handling this? Googling isn't getting me anywhere and I can't imagine that people are using the pen tool - it just isn't pratical.

Anyone want to point a girl in a direction?

Thanks :)

Comment: If Live Trace is unacceptable, you'd need to manually trace or draw the image in Illustrator.

Comment: Thanks... I'll take the word 'if' from that sentence and work on the theory that there must be a way of making Live Trace work.

Comment: It's possible that they don't want Live Trace or other "auto-trace" output because it produces too many control points. True vector drawings have the absolute minimum number of control points. Many RIPs (output engines) will choke on PostScript that contains thousands of points. Also, how the heck are you going to capture the subtle shading of a watercolor with solid-color shapes (there are ways, such as blended shapes, but again, they increase the complexity of the vector file.)

Comment: You should add one example image to the question. A part of a drawing is enough if it is in high resolution (=the same as you try to trace) and covers your different brushing styles. A web link also is possible if the image is too big to be included. Without it it's difficult to find any usable tricks other than "redraw it in a vector drawing program". No quarantee that some usable workarounds  will be found.